# How to query MySQL if data in one field look like 32;13;3;33 and the condition is where 3

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in which one column is filled with data like 32;3;13;33;43

so

```
SELECT * FROM table;
```

gives something like

name         ids
vegetables   13;3;63
fruits       37;73;333

When I'm querying MySQL like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ids LIKE '%3%'
```

it gives me both records but obviously I want only this containing 3.
How to query MySQL correctly?

Comment: ...and that's one of the about 20 reasons why you should not store comma separated values in a column. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574/447489

Comment: It's not me. The data are there already. Sometimes world is not perfect you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONCAT(';',ids,';') LIKE '%;3;%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to cover the case where it's the first in the list and the last.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ids LIKE '%;3;%' OR LIKE '%;3' OR LIKE '3;%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FIND_IN_SET, if you replace the ; with a , before checking the value:0

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('3', REPLACE(ids, ';', ','))
```